# How avoid hide rules warnings for c++ methods with equal names

Tags: c++, templates, overriding, overloading

I need to override a method and plus overload it with same name but different return type, see code below how I do this:

```
#include <iostream>
struct base_ttt
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct ttt : public base_ttt
{
   void foo() override
   {
       std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
   }

};

struct ttt2 : public ttt
{
    template<typename = void> 
    int foo()
    {
        std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
        ttt::foo();
        return 0;
    }
//protected:
   // using ttt::foo; //if uncomment this behaviour is changes 
};

int main()
{
    ttt2 tt;
    tt.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

This code just fine and outputs

```
2
1
```

As expected (tested on msvc 17.5.3 and gcc up to 12.2) .... BUT latest gcc (trunk) tested on godbolt generates warnings:

```
warning: 'virtual void ttt::foo()' was hidden [-Woverloaded-virtual=]
   16 |    void foo() final
```

but i cannot use using ttt::foo; because behaviour changes and calling `tt.foo();` actually calls virtual foo, but not templated foo. So output changes to

```
1
```

I have two questions:

1. How this approach(with templates same name method) looks like from standard side - it's legal?
2. If it's legal - how to officially avoid/suppress hide rule warnings - in other words how tell to compiler that I absolutely understand what I am doing

Comment: There is no `void foo() final` in the shown code.

Comment: inside `ttt2`, the `foo` function is not `virtual` and is **hiding** the original `foo` virtual method. This completely deserve the purpose of `virtual` functions, so the warning is highly desirable. What would you expect from the following code: `base_ttt* tt = new tt2; tt->foo();`?

Comment: "overload it with same name but different return type" - You cannot overload functions purely on return type in C++.

Comment: What you're doing seems like a very terrible idea.

Comment: There is no `here is no void foo() final` as @273K mentioned and also, line 16 is `struct ttt2 : public ttt`

Comment: It looks like an awful idea. What is the use case?

Comment: About final - sorry i change code different way - but it's not matter final or override - warning appear in both cases

Answer (score 4):

You will always get a warning if you try to declare your int-returning `foo` in a class that inherits a `virtual void foo()`.

Instead, you can declare it in a different class and inherit both of them:

```cpp
struct ttt2;

struct ttt2_foo_mixin {
    inline int foo();
};

struct ttt2 : ttt, ttt2_foo_mixin {
    using ttt2_foo_mixin::foo;  // Make it not ambiguous
};

int ttt2_foo_mixin::foo() {
    ttt2& self = static_cast<ttt2&>(*this);
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
    self.ttt::base();  // This is a non-virtual call
    // static_cast<ttt&>(self).base();  // If you wanted a virtual call
    return 0;
}
```

I could imagine some situations where this would be useful, but these seem better solved by making a [non-virtual interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern) (since you want some behaviour to change depending on the static type of an object)

```cpp
struct base_ttt {
    void foo() { xfoo(); }
protected:
    virtual void xfoo() = 0;
};

struct ttt : base_ttt {
protected:
    void xfoo() override {
        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct ttt2 : ttt {
    int foo() {
        std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
        xfoo();
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: unfortunally your code (ttt2_foo_mixin) also generates warnings on gcc(trunk) see https://godbolt.org/z/z86dW88T7